# Function graphics not showing with \tkzFct

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-fct

That's what I'm doing, everything works fine but the graphic of the function.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tkz-fct}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzInit[xmax= 110,xstep=10,
    ymax=6,ystep=1]
    \tkzDrawX[label={\textit{Age}},below= -18pt]
    \tkzLabelX
    \tkzDrawY[label={\textit{litres}}]
    \tkzFct[domain = 0.1:100 ]{50/\x}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Run this with the `-shell-escape` option. Or switch to pgfplots: `\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,xmax=115,ymax=6,xlabel=Age,ylabel=litres]
    \addplot[domain = 0.1:100,smooth,samples=101]{50/x};
 \end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Comment: Thx, Schrödinger's cat. I'm kind of used to \tkzFct and I never had this problem before, so I'd rather continue using it. What's the -shell-escape option?

Comment: What I meant by that is that if I compile your code with `pdflatex -shell-escape` the function appears. If I drop `-shell-escape` the plot is empty. You can also use `lualatex -shell-escape` or `xelatex -shell-escape` to compile your file.

Comment: What `-shell-escape` does is to allow `pdflatex` to execute other programs during the compilation. That's absolutely necessary for `tkz-fct`, because it calls on Gnuplot to do the calculations. If it worked before you must have had `-shell-escape`/`write18` (same thing) enabled, unwittingly or not.